# Error during page redirection (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try to make a page redirection according  to role using below code, somehow it gave me an error said that "The name 'Roles' does not exist in the current context". I don't have any clue what is wrong with my coding. Please help. Thanks.

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Aemy"))
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Home.aspx");
        else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "User"))
            Response.Redirect("~/Welcome/User1.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: i have faced the same problem before, try to rebuild the whole project

Comment: post the whole exception you are getting.

Comment: is it in compiling time or whilst running? if its in running, have you rebuild the project after the code changes?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a using statement for System.Web.Security in that file? I'm assuming here that you're receiving the error at compile time.

Edited for clarity:
The question here is, when do you get this error? If you're getting this error when you attempt to compile the project then it means it can't resolve "Roles" to the member of the System.Web.Security namespace which probably means that you're missing a "using System.Web.Security" statement near the top of your file. If you get this error at run time when someone attempts to login then you've hit on a much stranger exception.

Comment: I am sorry I don't really get you

Comment: He's saying that the compiler can't resolve the "Roles" object because there's a missing include directive. You could also rewrite it to be "System.Web.Security.Roles.IsInRole...". That would at least tell you if the problem is the missing include.